# URL CNAME Limitation?

Tags: dns, cname, amazon-web-services

We have a domain CNAME pointing to our Amazon load balancer, however the URL's that Amazon provides are longer than 32 characters and one of our clients DNS providers limits CNAME's to 32 characters.

Aside from moving to a diff DNS, any suggestions to get around this?  HTTP redirect not an option for the URL either....

Cheers,
Chad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is 1and1?  I don't know of any workaround that doesn't involve using a different DNS provider.  I don't know of anything in the RFC or related specs that call out a 32 char limit.  Have you asked the ISP with the limit why it's 32 chars?

Comment: host names are limited to 255 characters, with each label being limited to 63 characters